# OpenLayers 3.15.1 - styleFunction is executed every time I move/change the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm testing the new OpenLayers v3.15.1 and I've a simple question about `styleFunction` used to plot GeoJSON. 
My code contains:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: <my geoJson URL>,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:4326', 
        projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    })
});

var styleFunction = function(feature) {
    console.log('styleFunction');
    var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'black', width: 1});
    var fill = new ol.style.Fill({color: 'red'});
    var geom_name = feature.getGeometry().getType();
    var styles = {
            'Point': new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
                    fill: fill,
                    stroke: stroke,
                    points: 3,
                    radius: 7,
                })
            })
        }
    return styles[geom_name];
};

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: styleFunction
});
```

My GeoJSON contains more than 500 `Point` than running the map the first time the `styleFunction` is executed 500 times; moving the map, it is executed again 500 times and so on.

Looking the JavaScript console, I noticed that every time I move the map or I change the map zoom, the `styleFunction` is executed. Is this normal? Why the `style` should be rendered every time I move the map?

Comment: I've seen examples that modify point radius depending on the resolution dynamicly. So I guess it's normal.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you asign a function to the style this is normal. Function is executed for every single feature. It's time you move the map your features get updated and so function is executed again for every single fetaure.

If you dont want this attitude better asign a proper style instead of a function.

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                   color: 'black', 
                   width: 1
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'red'
                })
        })
     });
```

Comment: I don't see the use of reinserting style of features every-time you pan. The features could be thousands of features.

Comment: @wondim Thats why I am suggesting the solution above. In order to avoid style reasign for each feature on each pan.

Comment: I know but it is not considered to be normal. I feel like that is a limitation of openlayers than a normal behavior. Adding a style to the layer means, you cannot have style by feature attributes.

Comment: Its true, there are users complaining about this case. However, you may cache the styles and avoid this performance issue. check this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796548/openlayers-multiple-styles-for-different-geometry-types/40800098#40800098 and this --> http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch06-styling-vector-layers/example-07.html

Comment: I have done that and it didn't help. It will still run it for every feature that slow down everything. This is especially a problem when feature specific style is applied even at a layer level.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken...

You are assigning `styleFunction(feature)` to a vector layer, this as a consequence means that for every `feature` that is loaded by the `vectorSource` the `styleFunction(feature)` is executed.

You are applying the style to the features individually instead of applying a general style to the layer. It's possible to style features individually in OL3, see the documentation on [ol.Feature.setStyle](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#setStyle) and [ol.layer.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) for more info.

So in contrast to what [pavlos](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/60673/pavlos) said, you have to assign a style(without a function) to **`ol.layer.Vector`** and not to `ol.source.Vector`